# Xcode Profile vs Analyze

Tags: ios, xcode

In Xcode, we have the options between the following actions to apply to our app :

- Run
- Test
- Profile
- Analyze

Could you briefly explain what's the difference between each one ?

Comment: Profile is for profiling your app with instruments.  Analyze runs the static analyzer that looks for issues with your code.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

•`Run` will build and run the target on the selected device or simulator.

•`Test` will build your target and run its unit tests (YourTargetNameTests.m)

•`Profile` will build and run your target on the selected device or simulator with an Instruments tool of your choosing (Leaks, Allocations, etc.)

•`Analyze` will build your target using the static analyzer and let you know of certain types of bugs in your code.

Comment: What's the difference between the Analyze action and the Build action?

Comment: Build will not run the static analyzer.